# How can I get --debug and "watch" to coexist nicely?

Tags: node.js, debugging, port, watch

I realize there are a lot of related questions on this. None that I've found address this question.

I'd like my process to restart with `--debug` on when my code changes. Two commands in my package.json:

```
"debug-no-inspect": "API_PORT=5566 API_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG  node --debug dist/index.js  | bunyan -o short",
"watch": "watch 'npm run debug-no-inspect' ./src -d --wait=1",
```

OK those work nicely by themselves and work fine without `--debug`, but together the `--debug` will cause an EADDRINUSE error:

```
 Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858
```

Increasing the time to 4 seconds didn't do it. It works fine if I Ctrl-C and kill the watch and restart but that defeats the purpose. Is there a way to programmatically release that debugger port before restarting the process without killing all my node processes?

My best stab at this so far: Add a silly env variable (`ID=9877876` or `FINDME=alksdjflaksjdfl`) to the start command and then use that to find the process later and kill it before restarting:

```
"watch": "watch 'kill $(ps a | grep [ID]=9877876 | cut -d \" \" -f 1) && npm run debug-no-inspect' ./src -d"
```

However this does not work. The command works by itself but not with `watch`. Is another library a better choice?

Node 6; OSX; bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the solution was to remove `watch` and use [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage) instead:

package.json:

```
"watch": "nodemon -V  -w config  -w src -e coffee,yaml,properties --exec npm -- run debug",
```

Works just great.